# Do rubbing an eraser to the processor fixes it?

Tags: cpu

Our desktop computer at home automatically shutdown whenever.. err.. I don't know the reason. Anyways, my brother went to the place, where there was someone who fix computers, and let them checkup our CPU. Then he saw someone rubbing an eraser (yes the eraser we use when we were 5) to the processor, and with curiosity, he try it in our broken CPU, and to my surprise, our computer now works!

Doe's rubbing an eraser to the processor fixes it, or at least helps in fixing our CPU? Is there any static or something that helps it fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that that person was using an eraser to remove a left over thermal pad. It is not the tool I would use, but I guess careful application of an eraser could work.

If your home server shut down on it own, but no longer does that after you removed the CPU, cleaned it, added new thermal paste and properly reattached the heat sink then you might have had a heat problem. The eraser would not have fixed anything. Cleanly and correctly reinstalling the CPU might have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Base on my experience, my computer has no display or keeps on restarting, I thought I have a bad RAM slot, or the RAM is not working when together. I tried all the possible solutions like cleaning all the components, swapping RAM sticks, etc. but someone recommends me to clean the CPU with an eraser. So I did use an eraser to carefully clean the "gold plate" of my old CPU (i5-3330). I notice a thin white layer of dirt and carefully/lightly clean it off. Luckily my computer is now working. I can't say that this is a 100% solution but it really shows that dirt can interrupt our computers.

Answer (score 0):

Once my PC started shutting down automatically and on 3rd shutdown, it died like it won't turn on again. The fans spins but no scree. I took it to the PC repair shop, they put another CPU and the PC started working, they said your CPU died. So he later took an eraser and rubbed it under the processor then put it in the motherboard and bam the PC started right up.

So yeah I think the eraser does help to revive the CPU. I've heard that the same procedure also applies to RAM not working sometimes. They use eraser to fix RAM and it does work.